# Add attribute to a node java XML Serialization

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-serialization

I have an object I'm serializing with annotations:

```
@Component
@XmlRootElement(name="Stats")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Statistique
{
    @XmlElement(name="TotalUsers")
    private int nbUserTotal;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="UtilisateursParAppli")
    @XmlElement(name="Application")
    private List<Application> nbUserByAppli;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="SignaturePolicies")
    @XmlElement(name="SignaturePolicy")
    private List<String> signaturePolicies;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ValidationPolicies")
    @XmlElement(name="ValidationPolicy")
    private List<String> validationPolicies;

    ....
}
```

I want to add an attribute "count" on SignaturePolicies and ValidationPolicies node.
Is it possible to achieve that with XML Annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `@XmlElementWrapper` you will need to create two classes: `SignaturePolicies` and `ValidationPolicies` and work them into your domain model. Each of these will have the `count` property you wish to add and their corresponding collection (which they replaced on the `Statistique` class.

Comment: This is what I've done for an other node, but I thought there was a quick annotation for simple lists...

Comment: @thibon - To put any data on the wrapper element you need to create a new class.